# How do I save user input as the name of a class instance?

Tags: java, class, input

I'm trying to use a user-inputted string as the name for a class instance. In this example, I'm trying to use the user input to name the class instance `player1`. However, it is not letting me because `player1` is already defined when I set it as an instance of the `players` class.

```
System.out.println("Enter your name, player1: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//the user enters their name
String player1 = input.next();


players player1 = new players();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without pointing out the obvious of the variable names, I'll take a different approach at answering.

Maybe you want to take an input and actually set it as the `player`s name, in an OOP way. You obviously have a class `player`, so why not take in a `name` argument` in the constructor

```
public class Player {
    private String name;

    public Player(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then when you get the input you do this

```
String playerName = input.nextLine();
Player player1 = new Player(playerName);
```

Now when you create multiple `Player`'s they will each have a distinct `name`

---

Also you should follow Java naming convention. Class names start with capital letters

---

**UPDATE**

You need to create a new Player for every instance

```
String playerName = input.nextLine();
Player player1 = new Player(playerName);

playerName = input.nextLine();
Player player2 = new Player(playerName);

playerName = input.nextLine();
Player player3 = new Player(playerName);

playerName = input.nextLine();
Player player4 = new Player(playerName);
```

Comment: I believe that the statement regarding "pointing out the obvious" is a little bit of a stab. But maybe not. Regardless, +1 for mentioning naming conventions.

Comment: What do you mean not working? I don't get it. For every input, you need to create a new player. See my **UPDATE**

Comment: ohh shoot it's still not working. I don't know why, it makes sense but for some reason it still doesn't work. I think I might make a new post. But anyways, thanks for the great help; You taught me constructors :)

Comment: If you want to print the name, you need to use `player1.getName();`

Comment: Sorry about that; I put the accept back. Thanks for teaching me about constructors; even though the problem wasn't completely fixed I still learned from you!

Comment: I want to help you, but you haven't even explained what _isn't_ working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44538/discussion-between-user3133300-and-peeskillet)

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you'll want to do is pick a variable name that is meaningful. Just like in algebra, you don't use the input of a function as a variable name. But, you do treat the input as a replacement for a given variable name.

You could choose a more meaningful name for `player1`. Perhaps if you are expecting the user input to be a player's name, then `player1` as a string should be renamed to `playerName` and then `players player1 = new players();` can remain.

It's atypical and usually indicates poor design to expect a user to type something in and define one of your variable names.

Comment: "Perhaps if you are expecting the user input to be a player's name, then player as a string should be called playerName and then players player1 = new players(); can remain."     ---Yes I like this, but how do I set "playerName" and "player1" equal to each other?

Comment: "It's atypical and usually indicates poor design to expect a user to type something in and define one of your variable names."   ---- So what would you do if you wanted a player to input his own name (ex. Mark or Andy) to replace "player1"?

Comment: @user3133300 I wouldn't! I would actually just store the user's input in a variable, as you are doing here. User input is string input, so it goes in your string. Then, you have an instance of `players` stored in the variable `player1`. If you want them to be equal, they need to be of the same type or assignable from each other.